# Raspberry Pi B, wont play mp4 videos. Latest Rasbpian Stretch

Tags: raspbian, video

I'm trying to play mp4 video on vlc player, but it only shows progress and no video is playing. Also, tried with omxplayer, it just says, `Have a nice day ;)` and nothing happens.

I was looking for the solution online and this what I could do with my limited knowledge:

I complied vlc with H/A acceleration (according to this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=195221) ) and used this tutorial for codecs, though it says to be for RPi 3, I still tried. [enter link description here](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Configure-FFmpeg-with-H264-Codec-on-Raspberry-Pi-3)

I also changed this parameter `gpu_mem 448`

Video is playing normally on windows PC, here is mediainfo log:

```
General
Complete name               : G:\Laptop\loop.mp4
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                    : mp42 (mp42/mp41)
File size                   : 13.4 MiB
Duration                    : 7 s 880 ms
Overall bit rate            : 14.2 Mb/s
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-28 06:17:32
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-28 06:17:37
TIM                         : 00:00:00:00
TSC                         : 25
TSZ                         : 1

Video
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : High@L5.1
Format settings             : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames   : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP        : M=3, N=25
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 7 s 880 ms
Bit rate                    : 13.9 Mb/s
Width                       : 3 840 pixels
Height                      : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 25.000 FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.067
Stream size                 : 13.0 MiB (97%)
Language                    : English
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-28 06:17:33
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-28 06:17:33
Color range                 : Limited
Color primaries             : BT.709
Transfer characteristics    : BT.709
Matrix coefficients         : BT.709

Audio
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AAC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile              : LC
Codec ID                    : mp4a-40-2
Duration                    : 7 s 880 ms
Source duration             : 7 s 872 ms
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 317 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel positions           : Front: L R
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                  : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 305 KiB (2%)
Source stream size          : 305 KiB (2%)
Language                    : English
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-28 06:17:33
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-28 06:17:33
```

I cannot check audio from where I am right now and I do not need it anyway.

Thank you

Comment: It is Raspberry Pi 2 B, I missed it out :(((

Comment: The maximum  Profile/Level supported by hardware in pi is High/4.1 - even in your transcoded file you were using 4.2

Comment: Jaromanda X, thanks for reply, but it still does not work.

Comment: what doesn't? have you transcoded again? to 1080p HIgh/4.1?

Comment: yes, I am using premiere pro.

Comment: you could use apiece of string and ffmpeg, that's not the point :p

Answer (score 0):

Your video seems to be 8K. RPi hardware can only decode 1080p or smaller video frames, so hardware acceleration is largely irrelevant as it will not work. Software codecs typically won't play videos when they realize they cannot keep up with the framerate, so I guess that's what is happening.

Try converting your video to 1080p. Your RPi will not be able to output higher resolution anyway.